# Add Promise-Chain part in reuseable function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a bunch of functions which consist of a simple promise-chain which is mostly individual, anyway for all my functions a small block in the promise-chain is the same for all chains.

Example:

```js
function A() {
  DoSomethingA()
    .then(/* specific then block */)
    .then(/* general then block */)
    .then(/* general then block */)
    .then(/* specific then block */)
}

function B() {
  DoSomethingB()
    .then(/* specific then block */)
    .then(/* general then block */)
    .then(/* general then block */)
}
```

Now I want to have the "general then block" part be reusable variable/function so I can edit it for all functions at once when required. I just miss how I might handle this in the simplest way. Before and after the "general-then-blocks" there might be a undefined amount of "specific then blocks". The "general then blocks" always appear in this given order and always are exactly after each other.

Comment: Just put the code for each general block in its own function.  The argument passed to the function will be what comes from the previous `.then()` block and then return a promise.  As an `DoSomethingA().then(...).then(generalA).then(generalB)` where `generalA` and `generalB` are functions that accept a single argument and return a single value or promise.  You can then use `generalA` and `generalB` in other promise chains as long as the incoming argument and the return value are the same.

Comment: Was also my clue right after positing the question. Might it also be clever to have multiple promise-then-blocks in a function, and then return the whole promise instead of have generalA and generalB separated?

Still be interested in alternative ideas anyway

Comment: Look, putting common code into shared functions is absolutely no different whether programming with promises or not.  This exercise is not about promise programming. 
 If you have common code with the same inputs and expected outputs, you can wrap it in a function that you can share.  You look for the largest block of code that is common and you can share.  If the common part has multiple `.then()` in a row, then all that is common goes into the shared function.